# SELECT statement adds values together instead of displaying separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this piece of SQL:

```
SELECT SPELERS.naam, WEDSTRIJDEN.gewonnen +' - '+ WEDSTRIJDEN.verloren AS Uitslag
FROM SPELERS
INNER JOIN WEDSTRIJDEN
    ON SPELERS.spelersnr = WEDSTRIJDEN.spelersnr
WHERE WEDSTRIJDEN.gewonnen > WEDSTRIJDEN.verloren;
```

It suppose to display `TestName` `3 - 1`  <- example.

But right now its just adding the two values together, so it becomes `4` for some reason I don't know.

Comment: You need use concat() function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use CONCAT 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

try this

```
SELECT SPELERS.naam, 
CONCAT(WEDSTRIJDEN.gewonnen,' - ',WEDSTRIJDEN.verloren) AS Uitslag
FROM SPELERS
INNER JOIN WEDSTRIJDEN
    ON SPELERS.spelersnr = WEDSTRIJDEN.spelersnr
WHERE WEDSTRIJDEN.gewonnen > WEDSTRIJDEN.verloren;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT SPELERS.naam, CONCAT(WEDSTRIJDEN.gewonnen, '-', WEDSTRIJDEN.verloren) AS Uitslag
FROM SPELERS
INNER JOIN WEDSTRIJDEN ON SPELERS.spelersnr = WEDSTRIJDEN.spelersnr
WHERE WEDSTRIJDEN.gewonnen > WEDSTRIJDEN.verloren;
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat